# How to show countdown timer with link generating for download links in wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress, redirect, countdowntimer

I want to post some download links in wordpress. Those download links would be like this: https://exampaper.org/go/#https://karunya.edu

When i click on Download button it should goto [https://exampaper.org/go/](https://exampaper.org/go/#https://karunya.edu) there should display countdown timer of 5 sec . then generate a button titled as OPEN which is link with that external link https://karunya.edu

How to do this ? Need help